# How to change column dtype from object to Date/Time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

How to chage the datatypes of Data and Time columns from object datatype to Date and Time datatypes respectively? `pd_to_datetime` doesnot work.

[image]

```py
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

Comment: remove .dt.time and re-check dtype. datetime needs date and time.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to concat Date and Time columns first:

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].str.cat(df["Time"], sep=" "))
```

Or if you no longer need Date and Time columns after the concat:

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop("Date").str.cat(df.pop("Time"), sep=" "))
```